# Looking for reading recommendations: Theories of right/justice that safeguard against having one's job automated?

Tags: ethics, artificial-intelligence, justice, rights

Can anyone recommend any books or articles on AI automation of jobs?

Specifically, books that develop or discuss a theory of right and then apply it to the question of whether we should let job automation continue unimpeded, or whether regulations should intervene?

Even better if they apply this theory of right to creative industries like the arts.

Thanks!

Comment: The industrial revolution involved a great deal of job automation, and most modern people would consider that to be a positive development (but this certainly wasn't the case at the time) (climate considerations aside). You could potentially make arguments about ownership rights and such, but to say we should stop progress because it causes job automation seems backwards and averse to technological advancement.

Answer (score 1):

There are no rights toa particular job.  I think you re looking at this question a bit off from the more useful way to consider it.  Some technology advances improve society, but others do not.  With regulation, one can enhance society's adoption of new technologies.

The more useful approach would be to look at the societal consequences of technology in society.  The movement to do this is called "New Ludditism".  Here are a number of links that can elaborate:

https://theanarchistlibrary.org/library/kirkpatrick-sale-crow-s-nest-distribution-neo-luddites-and-lessons-from-the-luddites

https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/josp.12340

https://www.uvic.ca/humanities/philosophy/assets/docs/sophia/sophia2002/jpetch.htm

https://theconversation.com/im-a-luddite-you-should-be-one-too-163172